calculating infinite series sum: get different result depending on (i) if i differentiate first, or (ii) write out the terms then differentiate.
I had some trouble understanding why my solution to the infinite
series problem below did not work out to be
the same as what the fine folks at Khan Academy had for an answer.
Problem: Find the value of the third derivative of the function below, evaluated
at zero.
Their approach  -- explicitly writing out the first few terms and taking
the derivative of those terms, then evaluating the third derivative
at zero makes sense to me.  I just don't understand why my
approach, which is to take the first three derivatives of the
series expression and THEN plug in zero, why doesn't that work out to
be the same result?
First Khan Academy's provided solution:
Writing out the terms first, we get:
-2x + 2x^3/3! -2x^5/5!

$$
\begin{aligned}
& f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} \frac{2 x^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1)!} \\
& f^{\prime \prime \prime}(0)=\square
\end{aligned}
$$
1 / 2 Note that because we are interested in what happens at $x=0$, we only need to pay attention to the constant term in the series that represents $f$.
2/2 With that said, we now calculate derivatives. For clarity, we will work out one more term than we actually need to do the problem.
$$
\begin{aligned}
f^{\prime}(x) & =-2+\frac{6 x^2}{3!}-\frac{10 x^4}{5!}+\ldots  \newline \\
f^{\prime \prime}(x) & =\frac{12 x}{3!}-\frac{40 x^3}{5!}+\ldots \newline \\
f^{\prime \prime \prime}(x) & =\frac{12}{3!}-\frac{120 x^2}{5!}+\ldots
\end{aligned}
$$
So $f^{\prime \prime \prime}(0)=\frac{12}{3!}=2$.
My Approach
To find the third derivative of the given series, we'll start by writing down the series explicitly:
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2 x^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1)!}
$$
The series is differentiated term by term. Let's find the first three derivatives.
First derivative:
$$
\begin{gathered}
f^{\prime}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{d x}\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2 x^{2 n+1}}{(2 n+1)!}\right) \\
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2(2 n+1) x^{2 n}}{(2 n+1)!} \\
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2 x^{2 n}}{(2 n)!}
\end{gathered}
$$
Second derivative:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f^{\prime \prime}(x) & =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{d x}\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2 x^{2 n}}{(2 n)!}\right) \\
= & \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2 \cdot 2 n x^{2 n-1}}{(2 n)!} \\
= & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2 \cdot 2 n x^{2 n-1}}{(2 n)!}
\end{aligned}
$$
Here, the series starts from $n=1$ because the term for $n=0$ is zero.
Third derivative:
$$
\begin{gathered}
f^{\prime \prime \prime}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{d x}\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2 \cdot 2 n x^{2 n-1}}{(2 n)!}\right) \\
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 2 \cdot 2 n \cdot(2 n-1) x^{2 n-2}}{(2 n)!}
\end{gathered}
$$
The third derivative simplifies to:
$$
f^{\prime \prime \prime}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot 4 n(2 n-1) x^{2 n-2}}{(2 n)!}
$$
When I plug in 0 into the above equation it would seem to me that for every
'n'  when x=0 ->   x^(2n-2) would be 0 to some power, which would always
be zero would it not?   When n=1 we have 0^(2 * 1 - 2) which is zero to the zeroth
power, which is sometimes defined to be one.  If it were in this case then
the result of plugging in 0 to the third derivative would be the following
when n = 1:
-1^(1+1) *4*1(2*1-1)*x^(2*1-2)/(2n)! = 

-1^(2) * 4*(2-1)*x^(0)/(2)! = 


1  * 4 * (1) * x^(0)/2 = 

4 * x^(0)/2 =   4 * 1 / 2 = 2

which does work out.  So, the only thing I could think of that would make
both solution approaches work out the same is that we define 0^0 as 1.
Is that what happened, or is there some dumb mistake lurking in my steps.
thanks in advance !

This question would be better formatted using MathJax for the sections with arithmetic, see here for a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. In regards to your problem, quite often it is necessary to define $0^0=1$ with power series (look at the summation definition of the exponential and try to evaluate $exp(0)$ for example).

Thanks !    i suspected that was the reason. appreciate your confirming.  if you want to make your comment the official answer, i am happy to accept it.   and yeah.. mathJax.. i try.. but sometimes get stuck.
